# X-ray diffraction (is it possible?)

Tags: x-ray-crystallography

Is it possible to extract full lattice structure of a crystal from any of X-ray diffraction methods? (especially that the diffraction pattern is 2-Dimensional most of times)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I don't know about 'full' structure, it's probably specific to whether you want to find out the shape of a big lattice structure (something you can hold in your hand) or if you just want to find the microscopic arrangement of the lattice structure.
If you're interested in the microscopic arrangement (e.g. crystal structure, chemical composition, and physical properties of materials and thin films) then yes, you can.
If you're interested in finding information about the shape of houses from X-ray diffraction then I don't think so.

There are methods to :

-reveal information about the crystal structure, chemical composition, and physical properties of materials and thin films based on observing the scattered intensity of an X-ray beam.
[X-ray scattering techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_scattering_techniques)

-determining the atomic and molecular structure of a crystal, in which the crystalline atoms cause a beam of X-rays to diffract into many specific directions.
[X-ray crystallography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography)

-The crystal structure of a compound was determined from an X-ray powder diffraction
pattern.
[Determination of Crystal Structure by X-ray Diffraction](http://ed.augie.edu/~tmmcconv/e1.pdf)

[physics.valpo.edu/courses/p440/Diffraction_Crystal_Structure.ppt](http://physics.valpo.edu/courses/p440/Diffraction_Crystal_Structure.ppt)

Edit:
According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography),

> X-ray crystallography is a method of determining the atomic and
>   molecular structure of a crystal, in which the crystalline atoms cause
>   a beam of X-rays to diffract into many specific directions. By
>   measuring the angles and intensities of these diffracted beams, a
>   crystallographer can produce a three-dimensional picture of the
>   density of electrons within the crystal. From this electron density,
>   the mean positions of the atoms in the crystal can be determined, as
>   well as their chemical bonds, their disorder and various other
>   information.

and

> X-ray crystallography can locate every atom in a zeolite, an
>   aluminosilicate with many important applications, such as water
>   purification.

In a vague hand wavy intuitive sense, yes we can get entire information from X-ray scattering.

Comment: by full I meant entire information about the lattice, Thanks.

Comment: how big the lattice? did the links answer your question?

Comment: Im asking about the natural crytals (NaCl,...). I just started reading them. So you are saying the diffraction pattern has entire information in it right?

Comment: He is saying that it is not clear what you mean by "entire information".

Comment: In a vague hand wavy intuitive sense, yes we can get entire information from X-ray scattering. We need the " angles and intensities of these diffracted beams"-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography

Comment: @ Colin K, Let me rephrase, suppose I don't know the structure of the crystal that Im studying. How can I deduce the structure (which is 3dimensional) from (2D) diffraction pattern?

Comment: Richard - how big is the crystal? Raindrop's answer covers small crystals, but the larger the crystal, the more difficult it is to analyse the data. Too big, and you just can't do it .

Comment: @RoryAlsop, small crystals

Comment: btw I'm very unknowledgeable about this topic so to be sure about the information please rely on the quotes and not on what I said , what I said was based on my understanding from the quotes...